# Generic signature for tagged template literal function in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to find a way to return a string literal from a custom tagged literal template.

For example this fails.

```
function taggedLiteral(strings: TemplateStringsArray) {
  return strings[0]
}

const test: 'foobar' = taggedLiteral`foobar` // Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"foobar"'
```

Which makes sense. But the problem making this generic doesn't work at all because it seems that the `TemplateStringsArray` type is not itself generic.

```
// lib.es5.d.ts
interface TemplateStringsArray extends ReadonlyArray<string> {
    readonly raw: readonly string[];
}
```

So for example this function:

```
function taggedLiteral<T extends TemplateStringsArray>(strings: T): T[0] {
  return strings[0]
}

const test: 'foobar' = taggedLiteral`foobar` // same error
```

Still always just returns `string`.

Is there any way to define a tagged literal function which returns string literal types base don the input types?

Comment: There's an [open issue about TemplateStringsArray](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33304)

Comment: And it is not likely to be fixed/implemented any time soon https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/45310#issuecomment-947205767